# How can i do the same function using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi please I'm new to javascript and ajax and i read that to convert javascript ( client-side)variable  to php(server side) variable we have to pass by AJAX.
Please can someone give the the same code using AJAX. Here I'm using bad method but i just post this code to show what is my goal which is : when the user select an id from select tag HTML i want that others information appears in inputs tags (type text) so that he can modify the information
here is my source code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById('id').onchange = function(){
        var identifiant = document.getElementById('id').value;

        <?php  
        $phpvar='"+identifiant+"'; 
        $sql="select * from inscrits where id=".$phpvar;
        $res=mysql_query($sql) or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
        $ligne=mysql_fetch_array($res);


        ?>

        //document.getElementById('nom').value ="<?php echo $phpvar;?>";

        document.getElementById('nom').value = "<?php echo $ligne['nom'] ?>";
        document.getElementById('prenom').value = "<?php echo $ligne['prenom'] ?>";
        document.getElementById('profession').value = "<?php echo $ligne['profession'] ?>";
        document.getElementById('etablissement').value = "<?php echo $ligne['etablissement'] ?>";
        document.getElementById('telephone').value = "<?php echo $ligne['telephone'] ?>";
        document.getElementById('email').value = "<?php echo $ligne['email'] ?>";
        document.getElementById('acceptation').value = "<?php echo $ligne['acceptation'] ?>";
        }


</script>
```

Please appreciate my situation i'm new to javascript programming i just get started 
if it is possible to post me the code that i can use in same page.php thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything? Why are you assigning your values this way?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials on how to use ajax .. let google be your friend. What you are basically asking for is somone to write all the code for you and that's not how things work here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this, but here is a simple code that can help.  I got the code from an old book called Ajax in a Nutshell but modified it for you example,

create a php file lookupCustomer.php and add your php code in it with an additional change to i,

```
<?php  
        $phpvar = 'id';

        $sql="select * from inscrits where id=".$phpvar;
        $res=mysql_query($sql) or die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());
        $ligne=mysql_fetch_array($res);
         print_r(json_encode($ligne));

        ?>
```

Here is how you call the php script and update your form, again this is just a simplified way of doing this logic,

```
<html> 
 <head>
  <title>EXAMPLE</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  var xmlObj = (typeof window.ActiveXObject != 'undefined')
  ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  : new XMLHttpRequest();

  if (xmlObj == null)
     alert("Error creating request object!");

   function getCustomerInfo() 
   {
     var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
     var url = "lookupCustomer.php?id="+ escape(id);
     xmlObj.open("GET", url, true);
     xmlObj.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
     xmlObj.send(null);

     //* using POST instead of GET, use this code
     //var url = "lookupCustomer.php";
     //var req = "id="+ escape(id);
     //req = req + "?dummy=" + new Date().getTime();
     //document.getElementById("order").value = url;
     //xmlObj.open("POST", url, true);
     //xmlObj.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
     //xmlObj.send(null);
   }

   function updatePage() 
   {
     alert(xmlObj.readyState+" "+xmlObj.status);
     if (xmlObj.readyState == 4) 
     {
       if (xmlObj.status == 200) 
       {
         /* Get the response from the server */
         var customerAddress = xmlObj.responseText;
         /* Update the HTML web form */
        var linqne = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
        document.getElementById('nom').value           =  linqne.nom;
        document.getElementById('prenom').value        =  linqne.prenom;
        document.getElementById('profession').value    =  linqne.profession;
        document.getElementById('etablissement').value =  linqne.etablissement;
        document.getElementById('telephone').value     =  linqne.telephone;
        document.getElementById('email').value         =  linqne.email;
        document.getElementById('acceptation').value   =  linqne.acceptation;
       }
       else
       {
         var customerAddress = xmlObj.responseText;
        alert("Server return status error = "+xmlObj.status);
       }
     }
   }
  </script>
 </head>

 <body onLoad="document.forms[0].reset();">
  <p><img src="breakneck-logo.gif" alt="Break Neck Pizza" /></p>
  <form method="POST" action="lookupCustomer.php">
   <p>Enter your id number:
    <input type="text" size="14" name="id" id="id" onBlur="getCustomerInfo()" />
    <input type="text" size="20" name="nom" id="nom" />
    <input type="text" size="20" name="prenom" id="prenom" />
    <input type="text" size="20" name="profession" id="profession" />
    <input type="text" size="20" name="etablissement" id="etablissement" />
    <input type="text" size="20" name="telephone" id="telephone" />
    <input type="text" size="20" name="email" id="email" />
    <input type="text" size="20" name="acceptation" id="acceptation" />
   </p>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: change the first line to         $phpvar   = $_REQUEST['id'];